# How to make list items vertically centered?

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm stuck with this piece of code.

```
.hwrap header .h-position {
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 135px;
   position: fixed;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   justify-content: space-between;
}
```

These three elements should be vertically centered(as shown in pic)
[image: These three elements should be vertically centered(as shown in pic)]

[WHOLE CODE](https://codepen.io/alphanel/pen/VXpZQz)

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

move the `a` tag outside `nav` tag like this, no need to change anything else. run the `snippet` in `full-page` to see it in action

```css
body {
  background-color: #efefef;
  margin: 0px;
}

.hwrap {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.hwrap header {
  width: 135px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 30px 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
.hwrap header .h-position {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 135px;
  justify-content: center;
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
.hwrap header .logo {
  background-image: url(https://blog.codepen.io/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/Button-Fill-Black-Large.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
  height: 80px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.hwrap header nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 20px 0;
  padding: 0 20px 0 0;
  text-align: right;
}
.hwrap header nav li {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.hwrap header nav li:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.hwrap header .e-link {
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class='hwrap'>
  <header>
    <div class='h-position'>
    <div class='logo'></div>
    
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">3</a></li>
      </ul>
      
    </nav>
      <a href="mailto:ost.kost@gmail.com" class='e-link'>Email me</a>
     </div> 
   </div> 
  </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks mate, you helped a lot

Comment: if this has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. :) @jsjsjs

Comment: can you please accept my answer if it helped you @jsjsjs

Answer (score 2):

Here we go, just another way using display table, and table-cell, it accepts vertical align middle.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="inner-container">
        <ul class="list">
          <li>1</li>
          <li>2</li>
          <li>3</li>
          <li>4</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

css:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
}

.inner-container {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

you can check https://codepen.io/silabhijit/pen/oddjdg

Answer (score 0):

This this:

```
.hwrap header .h-position {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 135px;
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height:100%;
  align-items:center;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work: elements are in the same position and image has dissapeared